# This keeps giving me a syntax error on line 54 but I seriously can't figure out what it is

Tags: python

```
print("Use this program alongside a turnip forecaster")
price = input("Enter turnip buying price")
amt = input("Enter amount of turnips bought")
total = int(price) * int(amt)


monmin = input("Enter Monday minimum value here [-->]")
tuesmin = input("Enter Tuesday minimum value here [-->]")
wedmin = input("Enter Wednesday minimum value here [-->]")
thursmin = input("Enter Thursday minimum value here [-->]")
frimin = input("Enter Friday minimum value here [-->]")
satmin = input("Enter Saturday minimum value here [-->]")

mins = {"Monday min": int(monmin), 
        "Tuesday min": int(tuesmin), 
        "Wednesday min": int(wedmin), 
        "Thursday min": int(thursmin), 
        "Friday min": int(frimin), 
        "Saturday min": int(satmin)
}
monmax = input("Enter Monday max value here [-->]")
tuesmax = input("Enter Tuesday max value here [-->]")
wedmax = input("Enter Wednesday max value here [-->]")
thursmax = input("Enter Thursday max value here [-->]")
frimax = input("Enter Friday max value here [-->]")
satmax = input("Enter Saturday max value here [-->]")

maxes = {"Monday max": int(monmax), 
        "Tuesday max": int(tuesmax), 
        "Wednesday max": int(strwedmax), 
        "Thursday max": int(thursmax), 
        "Friday max": int(frimax), 
        "Saturday max": int(satmax)
}

monform_min = mins["Monday min"] * amt
tuesform_min = mins["Tuesday min"] * amt
wedform_min = mins["Wednesday min"] * amt
thursform_min = mins["Thursday min"] * amt
friform_min = mins["Fridaymin"] * amt
satform_min = mins["Saturdaymin"] * amt

monform_max = maxes["Mondaymax"] * amt
tuesform_max = maxes["Tuesday max"] * amt
wedform_max = maxes["Wednesday max"] * amt
thursform_max = maxes["Thursday max"] * amt
friform_max = maxes["Friday max"] * amt
satform_max = maxes["Saturday max"] * amt
print("Buying price = " + str(total))

print("""
Monday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + monform_min """
  Minimum net value: """ + monform_min - total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + monform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + monform_max - total
)

input('press 1 to see tuesday')

print("""Tuesday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + tuesform_min """
  Minimum net value: """ + tuesform_min - total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + tuesform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + tuesform_max - total
)

input('press 1 to see wednessday')

print("""wednesday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + wedform_min """
  Minimum net value: """ + wedform_min -= total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + wedform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + wedform_max -= total
)

input('press 1 to see thursday')

print("""Thursday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + thursform_min """
  Minimum net value: """ + thursform_min -= total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + thursform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + thursform_max -= total
)

input('press 1 to see tuesday')

print("""Friday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + friform_min """
  Minimum net value: """ + friform_min -= total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + friform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + friform_max -= total
)

input('press 1 to see saturday')

print("""Saturday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + satform_min """
  Minimum net value: """ + satform_min -= total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + satform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + satform_max -= total
)
```

I was trying to subtract a number from an equation and it gives me a syntax error and this keeps saying I need to add more details so its on line 54 in the string but since it's a multiline quote it doesn't point to exactly what the error is and I have no idea and it is STILL SAYING IT NEEDS MORE DETAILS IS THIS ENOUGH. how about now?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: You are missing `+` operators after `monform_min` and `total` and `monform_max`, and the same with all the other days.  You should use f-strings for formatting here.

Answer (score 3):

Line 54 appears to be the third line in the statement below:

```py
print("""
Monday:
  Minimum selling value: """ + monform_min """        # <-- this one.
  Minimum net value: """ + monform_min - total """
  
  Maximum selling value: """ + monform_max """
  Maximum net value: """ + monform_max - total
)
```

Is there some reason why you've left off the `+` before the final `"""` on that line, and quite a few other lines as well? I'm pretty certain you need them :-)

---

A better approach, by the way, would be to refactor that code out for re-usability, something like:

```py
def print_day(day, mini, maxi, total):
    print(f"{day}:")
    print(f"  Minimum selling value: {mini}")
    print(f"  Minimum net value:     {mini - total}")
    print(f"  Maximum selling value: {maxi}")
    print(f"  Maximum net value:     {maxi - total}")

# And call with the following:

print_day("Monday", monform_min, monform_max, total);
print_day("Tuesday", tueform_min, tueform_max, total);
# ... and so on
```

That will both:

- make your code more readable; and
- ensure any bug will have to be fixed in only one place, rather than all the places you cut'n'pasted that code to.

---

There are other opportunities for improvement as well. For example, whenever you see a group of *distinct* items/code-sections that are pretty much identical except for one minor attribute/code-action, you should be thinking "list" (or some other collection).

Iterating over a list, doing the same thing to each element, will give much more succinct, readable, and *maintainable*, code than a long sequence of duplicated code sections.

Comment: I believe this might be the first time I've seen a mysterious syntax error that _wasn't_ caused by a missing parentheses on the previous line!

Comment: @JohnGordon: yes, that's always the first thing I look for but, alas, not so in this case :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim Roberts commented, f-strings will make your print statements a lot cleaner:

```
print(f"""
Monday:
  Minimum selling value: {monform_min}
  Minimum net value: {monform_min - total}
  
  Maximum selling value: {monform_max}
  Maximum net value: {monform_max - total}"""
)
```